# box-shadow not showing on div element

Tags: css

I'm trying to add box-shadow to a `<div>` element but it just doesn't show up.

I've already tried adding height and width in px to the class and tried using z-index on class and parents, nothing worked for me.

Here's the code. https://codepen.io/mateus-ramos/pen/BaBbyMG

I want to add shadow to ".imagem-container" class.

Comment: I don't think your shadow is big enough, you may find this article helpful https://css-tricks.com/using-box-shadows-and-clip-path-together/ since you're using clip-path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clip path is cutting off your shadow. A workaround for this is to create a parent div for the element, then put the box-shadow on that. Then use filter to follow the path of your imagem-container (otherwise it will be a square box shadow). This article might help: https://css-tricks.com/using-box-shadows-and-clip-path-together/

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a `drop-shadow` filter in the parent div, so the effect can be shown. In your code add this into the .job class

```
.job { /*parent div of .imagem-container*/
  display: flex;
  padding: 5%;
  height: 500px;
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
}
```

The problem in your case is that the shadow is applied to the text as well. You need to create a parent div only for your `.imagem-container` div, the text can be outside of that scope and the effect doesn't apply to all the content.